# How does atoi() actually work

Tags: c, atoi

**This is the Code :**

```
#include <ctype.h>

/* atoi:  convert s to integer; version 2 */
int atoi(char s[])
{
int i, n, sign;

for (i = 0; isspace(s[i]); i++)  /* skip white space */
    ;
sign = (s[i] == '-') ? -1 : 1;
if (s[i] == '+' || s[i] == '-')  /* skip sign */
    i++;
for (n = 0; isdigit(s[i]); i++)
    n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');
return sign * n;
}
```

Q1) The first line of code counts white space? That means it counts spaces, enter, return etc? Say my string starts after two spaces is it? And after counting white spaces i value has been incremented?

Q2) the next sign line calculates if string is like `-234`? or `234`?

Q3) next line if it has `+` or `-` sign count them in `i` which has already been incremented by calculated white spaces? is it?

Q4) next line calculates the number in the string say `234`. `n= 10*n+ ('2'-'0')` => `i` get `2` => `n`= `10*2 + ('3'-'0')` => `i` get `23` and at last `i` get number `234`

and in the last line multiply `234` with `-1` or `+1` whatever the answer is*

Do I understand this code correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A1) No, it counts only white spaces in the beginning of line (white spaces in standard isspace() implementation are ' ', '\t', '\n', '\v', '\f', '\r'; i.e. space, tabs, newline, feed and carriage return).

A2) Yes, it determines sign of value.

A3) If value is "234" it will not increment i. But if value is "+234" or "-234" we need to increment i (to recognize digits after it).

A4) Yes. But not '24' (it looks like misprint; there must be '23').

Comment: aren't these white (enter, space, return) included in whitespace characters i read it wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

Comment: @Abhimanyu: uh, sure (and why do you have to ask?). You might want to read a C reference instead of Wikipedia, though.

Comment: @Abhimanyu: It is better to read http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/ about isspace() function.